# PHP converting utf8 Æ (195 134) to 198

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a strange problem in PHP, hopefully someone has seen this before.

I am storing the Æ character (AE) in a MySql database that is set to utf8.  I have a PHP application that displays the character in a browser correctly on my local machine (Windows 7), but when the same code and database are used in production (GoDaddy Linux Hosting), the character is being converted to a single ASCII character (198), which displays as the dreaded question mark in a black triangle.  I have confirmed that the database and code are exactly the same in both places.  I can iterate over the bytes as an array and see that what is coming out of MySql is two bytes, \195 \134, but what PHP sends has been converted somehow in the production environment to a single 198.

I have ruled out browser issues with character encoding.  I get the same behavior in all browsers using utf8 encoding.  I can look at the raw response and see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a suspicion that the PDO connection was the culprit, but I thought I was covered by my initialization code.  Turns out, it doesn't work on all platforms.  In addition to adding "set names 'utf8'" as a PDO attribute, you also (or instead) need to actually execute a query with the command before using the PDO reference.

```
// This doesn't seem to work on all platforms
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

// This seems like a hack, but it works on GoDaddy Linux Hosting
$sth = $pdo->prepare("set names 'utf8'");
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: I use only one command after opening the connection: `$pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`. I have never had any problems but I do not use godaddy...

Comment: Have you tried to use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` [as shown in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php), as *argument for the constructor*?

Answer (score 1):

If

```
UTF8: \xC3\x86 (195 134) - LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE (U+00C6)
```

Is converted to `198`, it looks like that it is interpreted as:

```
ISO-8859-1       \xC6 198    UTF8: \xC3\x86        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE (U+00C6)
ISO-8859-4       \xC6 198    UTF8: \xC3\x86        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE (U+00C6)
ISO-8859-9       \xC6 198    UTF8: \xC3\x86        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE (U+00C6)
ISO-8859-15      \xC6 198    UTF8: \xC3\x86        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE (U+00C6)
Windows 1252     \xC6 198    UTF8: \xC3\x86        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE (U+00C6)
Windows 1254     \xC6 198    UTF8: \xC3\x86        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE (U+00C6)
Windows 1258     \xC6 198    UTF8: \xC3\x86        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE (U+00C6)
```

Choose any of these, all match the `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE` at codepoint 198 decimal.

Check your encoding settings for PHP output as well as for the database client connection that everything is setup as UTF-8.

Comment: I've checked everything I can think of.  I have "set names 'utf8'" in my PDO connection, which is a common solution to problems like this, but it's not working.

Comment: Might not cause your issue, but `set names utf8` is not recommended. Specify the client charset as a connection parameter when you connect to mysql with PDO. If you have PHP 5.3.6 or higher, see [PHP MySQL PDO `charset` DSN component](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php#refsect1-ref.pdo-mysql.connection-description).

Comment: How did the database went from windows to linux? I ask because probably when you exported / imported the data it might have been converted into some other encoding and it's already broken inside the database.